# Why do some download links ask for Gmail login?

Tags: gmail

Recently I have clicked on download movie from a website, it has redirected me to my Gmail login and after I have finished logging into gmail, a download link is generated and I am able to download a movie.

After that I found that an approximately 2GB movie file was also generated in my google drive, and after that I deleted those files from my Google drive & changed my password also.

So my question is why was the same movie which I downloaded then uploaded on Google drive, and is it any kind of hacking attempt or what, and if is it hacking then what should I do to prevent it?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldnt be downloading pirated movies from sketchy websites.

Comment: @Keltari  "same movie which I have downloaded is uploaded on google drive also" - while indeed there is a chance it was malicious site, it could even be a legitimate one offering to load the movie to Google drive. Without knowing the website and how exactly permission was requested, it's impossible to decide

Comment: @MátéJuhász - There are no legitimate websites, which allow you to purchase a movie, and upload it to Google Drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did the right thing to delete the movie from Google Drive and change your Google password. You have been exploited by what seems to be a fake Google login page that was used by a hacker to access your Google password.

Hackers prey on your ignorance. Whenever you are confronted with an unusual login request from what appears to be a website that you signed up for, don't give them your password. If you get a login request from some website that you have never seen before that looks like it may be designed to imitate a legitimate Google website,  don't give them your password. If you need to login to Google, login from a new browser session at Google's webpage, not from some movie download website or what may be a fake Google webpage that offers you an opportunity to sign up for what it claims is an experimental new feature of a Google web application. That gives you control of when you input your password and denies control to hackers.

Answer (score 2):

I also have faced same kind of issue & found that it was an hacking attempt.

By creating fake google login page, hackers will retrieve your username & password so you must not have to download movies such websites.

To prevent such attempt best way is not to surf or download movies or anything from such websites.

Such kind of hacking called `phishing attack` you can find many references online about it if you will do google..